# Two Public subnets can not communicate with private ip

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a VPC where two public subnet is there.

1. React (Public subnet 1)
2. Node (Public subnet 2)

On React side there is a code where Node API is called with the help of fetch.

When I Pass the Public IP of Nodejs to the url of `fetch` then communication is happen, 
If I change public IP to Node Instance Private IP then Communication is not happened.

I check curl command i.e

```
curl http://NodeInstance public_ip:port/ -> return Response
curl http://NodeInstance private_ip:port/ -> return Response.
```

I don't understand that why private Ip is not work on API call from React. My curl command works fine. It returns the response from both public and priavte IP.

Any Help is really Appreciated for that.

```
I am using Single security group for both the instance i.e

Type     |     protocol     |     port range     |     source
All TCP        TCP                0-65535              0.0.0.0/0
SSH            TCP                22                   0.0.0.0/0
All ICMP-IPV$  All                N/A                  0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Your react code is running on the client's browser so unless that browser happens to have a route to your VPC's private address space then it's not going to be able to connect to the private IP.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR really appreciate for your reply. Can you share me how to achieve this. i mean this is not safe to call backend server everytime using public ip

Comment: I have Both Public subnet on VPC with attached Internet Gateway

Comment: Why is it not safe? The React code is running in your users browser, if it needs to talk to another server then it will need to do it via a public IP address.

Comment: But Why it needs public Ip If they both are in same VPC. Example is If We are in home then our parents will call us by our nick name not the official name. We will also save money if the communication is happened with Private IP rather than public IP

Comment: Because the React server is not talking to the Node server. The React server serves JS that is ran by the browser that then needs to talk to the Node server.

Comment: So according to You all over the world everyone do this. For Frontend Request they call the backend server with public ip instead of private IP?

Comment: @Aks that is correct.  "fetch" occurs on the browser.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Will you elaborate sir. I didn't get

Answer (score 2):

Even though you run the React code and the NodeJs code in the same VPC, when you run the program, the React code gets pushed to the browser. So when the end-user tries to use the app and starts calling the backend API through the private IP from a browser which is outside your VPC, the call won't reach the Node server. One solution for this is to create a reverse proxy using something like Nginx. Nginx will sit inside the VPC(Public subnet 1) and handle the communication between the browser and the backend API.

[image: Network example]

Here's a sample config

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name example.com;

  location /api/getitems {
      proxy_pass https://yourprivatip/api/getitems;
  }
}
```

More on Nginx reverse proxy: [Link](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/use-nginx-reverse-proxy/)

Note: *You can also create a reverse proxy using NodeJs.*